# VM in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine

I am trying to upload photos/images on VM in Google Cloud.
Now, I try to use this photo to be published online. However, every time trying to do that the photo doesn't appear and got that error '404 Not Found'.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

I tried this code

Here is the code I used in SSH, I try to upload the photo on web server

```
echo '<!doctype html><html></html> <img src="photo1.jpg"> ' | sudo tee /var/www/html/index.html
```

I add the image as 'photo1.jpg' in  tag

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming the problem to your code, your image source is not specify clearly, here's
the example code below :

How to insert images from another folder or from another web site :

```
<img src="/images/stickman.gif" alt="Stickman" width="24" height="39">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt="Lamp" width="32" height="32">
```

or

1. Always verify your web services if still up or down.
2. Verify your port 80 if already open before the access test

For additional information of ports you can use this [link](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/network-layer/what-is-a-computer-port/)

Comment: Hi Jeffrey,thanks for your comments. 
That is the same code as I used but when run the web server I got a message that it is not possible to access the file from the VM. It sounds I need to make the file public so it can be read, but I am not sure how I can do that

Comment: I think you need to purchase a public IP address from Godaddy, cloudflare or GCP , then you will need to configure the DNS from your Name server to publish your web server.